# WicketTester fails if wicket page accesses system properties

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to use WicketTester to test my pages.

On some pages I access System Property. The value read affects display of page. However when I try to test these pages using WicketTester, 'NullPointerException' exception is thrown.

I presume this exception is thrown since the property set on Payara server is not available to WicketTester when testing the page.

What should I do to test these type of pages?

Complete code, created using 'wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html' for test is available at 'https://github.com/rjngshn/WicketTesterSession'. In this project I am trying to test 'TestUserPage2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WicketTester is executed inside a unit test. It has nothing to do with Payara or any other web servlet container.

You need to set the system property yourself in the unit test with `System.setProperty(..., ...)` before using WicketTester.

Comment: Thanks **martin-g**. That works like a charm. Much appreciated.